# jQuery dialog load a tabbed from url not working

Tags: opencart, jquery-dialog, jquery-tabs

I am working on opencart. I tried to create a modal dialog popup every time user click a link that contains a product page. That links has a tabs inside (review,description). It load successfully, but the tabs are not working. How can i fix this?

This is how i call this:

```js
$('a[href*="index.php?route=product/product"]').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    showDialog(this.href);
});

$("#dialog-modal").dialog({  //create dialog, but keep it closed
   autoOpen: false,
   height: 550,
   width: 1000,
   position: "center",
   modal: true,
   close: function(event, ui) { $('#wrap').show(); },
   open: function(event, ui) { $('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click', function(){ $("#dialog-modal").dialog('close'); }); }
});

function showDialog(urlToLoad){  //load content and open dialog
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: urlToLoad,
        success: function( returnedData ) {
            var $html = $(returnedData);
            var content = $html.find('#content').find('.breadcrumb').remove();
            content = $html.find('#content').html();
            var container = document.getElementById('dialog-content');
            container.innerHTML = content;
            $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
            $('#tabs a').tabs();
      }
    });
}
```

Apparently the **$('#tabs a').tabs();** after **$("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");** is not working.

Comment: If You have the content being loaded into the modal window already prepared on the page and You are opening a modal window while duplicating the content HTML part (because the content loaded from page is copied into the modal HTML) then You have two elements with ID `tabs` -> therefore the jQuery selector may not work anymore. Change the ID attribute for class and change the selector to `$('.tabs a')`.

Comment: tried this but still not working. :( Actually, the modal window is blank for the first time. After i click a product, the modal window load the page.

Comment: It is then highly possible that events that should be listened to within tab extension are not propagated to newly created content even if You initialize the tabs after content is copied and re-rendered. Could You create a paste bin project with Your current HTML, jQuery plugins (for modal and tabs) and post the link here?

Comment: this is the page that i call http://pastebin.com/JHmU60zK, the caller is in the footer http://pastebin.com/Wt7BdG8S

Comment: And what about moving the `$('.tabs a').tabs();` part from `.success` callback to `.complete` callback? Either way I do not know, I would have to have a working example to try it myself...

Comment: it, still not working. i already made a copy of my project in my vps. Maybe you it make it more clear. it is http://semuafurniture.dwiprawira.info/
when i click the product, it shows pop up, but the tab is not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solve this. It's just a silly problem, i forgot to import the jquerytabs.js in my caller page. So the tabs() function doesn't work. Now it's work perfectly.